# It shows "error: NameError: name 'c_wchar' is not defined." in wintypes.py

Tags: x86-64, ctypes, python-3.3

I am using python33 on OS-64bit win7 environment.
I can't find ctypes for 64bit with python33.
I just use ctypes for 64bit with python25 and try to revise it.
I've use 2to3.py to translate it.
When I run the code which import ctypes

```
import ctypes

BYTE = ctypes.c_byte
WORD = ctypes.c_ushort
DWORD = ctypes.c_ulong
CHAR = ctypes.c_char
WCHAR = ctypes.c_wchar
```

It shows "error: NameError: name 'c_wchar' is not defined." in wintypes.py

please help and thank you.

Comment: Hi eryksun, 

I've done what you recommend. But I got below error.
 
File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: @eryksun
here is my current code which has error on it.
'return cdll.fdd.fdd_get(self.test1.ctypes.data,
                        self.test2.ctypes.data,
                        self.test3.ctypes.data,
                        self.test4.ctypes.data)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been fixed.
The problem is a dll file which I am using is compiled with 32bit.
When the dll file re-compiled with 64bit, the problem is gone.

For all of you to be the reference.